# rails 3 sanitize sql in offset method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
  offset = params[:offset]

  Player.order('rank desc').
        limit(RESULTS_PER_PAGE).
        offset(['?', offset])
```

I want to sanitize the offset that is sent by the user.
The above seems to work in where methods, but doesn't work here.

Ideas on how to sanitize this offset without writing out the whole query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `offset = params[:offset].to_i` as explained in [Rails' Security Mailing List](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-security/browse_thread/thread/b658902cf6bf4eed?pli=1)

Comment: cool. that's what i'm doing now (offset.to_i.abs) - was wondering if I might be missing a hack that could get by this